# Saving token is postman envvar automatically not working

Tags: javascript, jwt, postman

API Response :

```
{
 "token" :"eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCfhfgJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJ1c2VyX2lkIjoyLCJ1c2VybmFtZSI6ImRiYWRtaW5AY2lkbnkub3JnIiwiZXhwIjoxNjMyNTY3OTY1LCJlbWFphbCI6ImRiYWRtaW5AY2gjglkbnkub3JnIiwib3JpZ19pYXQiOjE2MzI1NDk5NjV9.3ZtHRy0_jBao7hvQLSVcQuvIMIgjgjg7mmvKqlegS5Jo0-Q"
}
```

This is in Test

```
var res = pm.response.json();
pm.environment.set('env',token);
```

This is expected to save the token in env variable but the token did not work after saving.

What is the issue here?

Comment: `res.token` maybe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this , it should work:

```
var res = pm.response.json();
pm.environment.set('env',res.token);
```

Basically the token you saved contained full response, not the token only.

Answer (score 0):

```
var {token} = pm.response.json();
pm.environment.set('env',token);
```

You should access the property , you can access it by pm.response.json().token or by using destructure assignment